# Loading UISplitViewController on UIButton click

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

The Flow of my application is

***Application Starts -> TopMenuViewController ( Which Contains Several Buttons & navigation controller ) -> When particular button is clicked -> Load Split View Controller***. 
The user can go back to TopViewController. In short I want to load `UISplitViewController` on button click. How to do this? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there's no good way to load a `UISplitViewController` on demand like that.  It has to be the root of your entire user interface, or you will pull your hair out trying to make things work.

I've reworked several app designs to fit into this requirement, and it's generally not been difficult at all to come up with something functional and attractive which fits into the split-view-at-all-times paradigm.  You can freely swap the views loaded into each side of the split with login panels, empty placeholders, etc. to make your flow work with the splitview.

There are third-party split view controllers that mimic Apple's and allow later loading (as well as master pane visibility in portrait, and other features).  One is Matt Gemmell's [`MGSplitViewController`](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad).  You could also come up with a different presentation altogether for your master-detail hierarchy.